# Python : Help on Random Number Code

Tags: python, random, numbers

Here is my code for the random nuumber generator. User inputs largest and smallest number and gets random number.

```
import random
Smallest_Number = raw_input('Enter Smallest Number: ')
Largest_Number = raw_input('Enter Largest Number: ')
print random.randint(Smallest_Number,Largest_Number)
```

Here's the error in console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Matthew/Documents/python/Random Number.py", line 7, in <module>
print random.randint(Smallest_Number,Largest_Number)
File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 242, in randint
return self.randrange(a, b+1)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

What am I doing wrong? Help needed and appreciated!

Comment: convert the input to `int`.

Comment: This is not a forum. Never edit your question into a different question once your initial question is answered; don't use an answer for anything but _information that answers the question_, and a comment saying "Bump" does exactly nothing. You could in theory ask a different question for your new problem, but given your obvious lack of understanding of the python and SO basics I'd suggest you study the language by yourself first; and re-read the SO tour and help center before asking your next question.

Answer (score 1):

[`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string. `randint` requires ints. You can convert strings to ints using `int()`.

```
smallest_number = int(raw_input('Enter Smallest Number: '))
largest_number = int(raw_input('Enter Largest Number: '))
print random.randint(smallest_number, largest_number)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I think this would help! It works now beautifully! Problem solved!

Comment: You can also use `input` instead of `raw_input`. In this way you don't have to convert data to int

Comment: @AshokaLella: Please don't encourage people to use `input()` in Python 2, since it's effectively `eval(raw_input())` and calling `eval()` on untrusted data can be [dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). In Python 3 `input()` behaves like Python 2's `raw_input()`, so it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` returns a `string` object, so `Smallest_Number` and `Largest_Number` are both strings.

`random.randint` expects integers, so you need to convert the strings:

```
import random
Smallest_Number = raw_input('Enter Smallest Number: ')
Largest_Number = raw_input('Enter Largest Number: ')
print random.randint(int(Smallest_Number), int(Largest_Number))
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I think this would help! It works now beautifully! Problem solved!